# Difference in getLine functionality with GHCi vs. runhaskell

Tags: haskell, io, ghci, runhaskell

I've just stumbled upon a thing I don't understand.

If I am using GHCi and use `getLine` I get the following

```
Prelude> a <- getLine
Test<Backspace>oo<CR> -- the Backspace action results in a '^?'
Prelude> a
"Test\DELoo"
```

If I write the **same** in a Haskell file

```
module Main where

main :: IO ()
main = do a <- getLine
          putStrLn a
```

and run the script with runhaskell and enter the same input, the backspace deletes the 't' as expected.

Why is there a difference?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is due to different buffering behaviour in GHCi and GHC. GHCi has stdin (standard input stream) using `NoBuffering` by default, and GHC-compiled binaries / `runhaskell` use `LineBuffering` by default. If you explicitly do

```
hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
```

in your Haskell program, you'll be able to reproduce the GHCi behaviour. If you do

```
hSetBuffering stdin LineBuffering
```

in GHCi, you'll have lots of unwanted side effects, but can reproduce the `runhaskell` behaviour.

Comment: you say that I would `have a lot of unwanted side effects`, are they just in ghci unwanted or is there some kind of protection against it in a compiled version - can you elaborate on this a bit more?

Comment: wether you do or not - I'll accept this answer as soon as I can!

Comment: They're unwanted in GHCi. It will mess with the way that GHCi itself reads inputs, so when you type in stuff for GHCi to run, you'll only see them show up once you hit the Return key.

Comment: So is there a way to delete/revise your input while using `getLine` in GHCi?

Comment: @JoshCaswell What do you mean? Line-editing such as e.g. `haskeline` provides?

Comment: I'll have a look at that, thanks. My need is probably far more basic: I'm working through the School of Expression book, which used `getLine`, and I ran into this. It's just an annoyance, though, hardly a showstopper.